# Change webservice reference in dotnet 1.1 application

Tags: .net, web-services

Few years ago I had create a web service in dot-net 1.1 and deployed it in many application which are developed in dot-net 1.1 and 2.0. Now i want to convert this web service in dot-net 2.0 with some changes. My problem is i can't changed reference and build applications again where i had deployed this web service. Please tell me how can i changed new web service in applications (developed in 1.1 and 2.0) without build again.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service reference was created as dynamic you can update the config file to point to the new web service otherwise it'll be hardcoded into the Proxy and therefore require a recompile.  Either way if the data contract for the service changes the clients will need to be updated to reflect this.

You could perhaps update the existing web service to become a wrapper to the new service but the existing clients would obviously still be restricted to the API of the old web service and performance may become an issue.